# Trouble with footer in Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, footer, contact-form

I am working on a website in Bootstrap 4 and am using the footer at https://www.codeply.com/go/7TzhebXBdX/bootstrap-4-footer-with-contact-form

I have changed a little of it and, while it is great in the browser, it breaks down in responsive mode. The background color stops about half way down the footer and the rest is shown with a white background. The submit/reset buttons are mostly off the page.

I have been working on this for a few days and can't seem to get it to work in responsive mode.

The footer can be seen here: http://leeunderwood.org/_tmp/index.html

The code for the footer is:

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h4 class="footer-logo-text"><i class="fa fa-book"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;spreading biblical truth in a darkened world ...</h4>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-10">
                      <p>
                      The goal here is to separate myth, traditions, pagan practices, and man-made stories from the truth of the Hebrew Scriptures. Many people believe that because something has been written, taught, or practiced for centuries, or even decades, it must be scriptural. Yet nothing could be further from the truth. Time does not necessarily prove the validity of something. It's therefore important to research these writings, teachings, practices, and beliefs to determine their origin and whether they actually do have a scriptural basis. <a href="/about.html" class="text-light bg-dark">more ...</a></p>
<br>
<p style="font-size:90%;margin-bottom:0;">
This Website is not affiliated with any government, institution, organization, religious group, or political establishment. Copyright &copy; 2004 - <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> | This template is made with <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> by <a href="https://colorlib.com" target="_blank">Colorlib.</a> Customization has been done by site owner.</p>

        </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link pl-0"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-github fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">

<p class="contactUs"><a id="contactMe">Contact Us</a></p>

<!--   beginning of form   -->

<form id="myForm" class="contact__form" method="post" action="mailContact.php">

    <!-- form message -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="alert alert-success contact__msg" style="display: none" role="alert">
                Your message was sent successfully.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end message -->

    <!-- form element -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>
<!--               <input id="test_email" name="email" size="25" type="text" value="" />   -->
        <div class="col-12 form-group">
            <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="6" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Send Message">  <input class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset form">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end form element -->
</form>

<!--   end of form   -->

            </div>
        </div>

<!--   Footer design from: https://www.codeply.com/go/7TzhebXBdX/bootstrap-4-footer-with-contact-form redesigned by Lee Underwood   -->
<!--   Contact form code from: https://themehunt.com/blog/53-tutorial/162-how-to-create-an-ajax-contact-form-without-any-plugin   -->
</footer>
```

The CSS is:

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 300px;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

/* Taller footer on small screens */
@media (max-width: 34em) {
    body {
      margin-bottom: 500px;
    }
    .footer {
      height: 500px;
    }
}

footer {
  padding-top:30px;
  padding-bottom:20px;
  background-color: #2F4454;
  color:#bbb;
  font: 400 13px/1.2em 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
}

footer a {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration:none;
}

footer a:hover, footer a:focus {
  color: #aaa;
  text-decoration:none;
  border-bottom:1px dotted #999;
}

footer .form-control {
  background-color: #1f2022;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border: none;
  resize: none;
  color: #d1d2d2;
  padding: 0.7em 1em;
}

.form-control {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

I sure could use a bit of help here. Anything else needed just let me know.

Comment: I checked your issue and it solution is to set  footer height dynamic using jquery also set body bottom margin using dynamic for example.

Comment: on window load  and resize event set footer height like $('footer.footer').css('height',footHeight); function fooHeight(){return $('footer.foooter').outerHeight()} and same as margin for body like $('body').css('margin-bottom', footHeight); I hope this work for you.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with jquery. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Yes, sure. jQuery is a JavaScript Library. It is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library. It makes things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling, animation, and Ajax much simpler with an easy-to-use API that works across a multitude of browsers. You can get more detail from it the site like[https://jquery.com/] if you still have an issue plz let me know.

Comment: Sorry, I know what jquery is. I am just not familiar with using it or JavaScript, except for plugins, snippets and such. I did some research over at the jquery site but it's way over my head. Any suggestions?

Comment: Okay, No problem let me give you the solution in detail in an answer with code. You just need to include js library file and create one js file like script.js file and put it before </body> in your site pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to have solved the problem myself. I went back to the [original footer](https://www.codeply.com/go/7TzhebXBdX/bootstrap-4-footer-with-contact-form) and started over. (It works online so I must have changed something, right?) This time I removed some of the text on the left side so as not to make it so long (that was what was pushing it down too far). Now it seems to works fine.

Thanks to all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is the code for script.js which I mention in my above comment.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setDynamicHeightFooter();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    setDynamicHeightFooter();
})

function footHeight(){
    return $('footer.foooter .container').outerHeight()
}

function setDynamicHeightFooter(){
    $('footer.footer').css('height',footHeight);
    $('body').css('margin-bottom', footHeight);
}
```

As I mentioned in comment you need one jquery file you can download it from jquery site or direct add CDN link for jquery library like..
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js

I hope this will work you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should increase the height in the media query until it accomodates all of the footer content.

```
@media (max-width: 34em){
  .footer {
    height: 700px;
  }
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
}
```

Comment: It works fine for 480x320 but not for 320x480, 600x800, 800x600, 768x1024, 1024x768.